# Create a JSON parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I want to call a API with a post and give it parameters about the body. I need the parameter in following style.

```
"linked_users": [ "5dc73d6e1c20540b24336681", "5dca64f4bf98ec2ada3b315e"]
```

In Postman the json above is working, but if I create it I Swift, I get a bad request parsing error from the API.

```
var linkedUserString = ""

if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: stringArray, options: []){
    if let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    {
        linkedUserString = json
    }
}
```

The value of linkedUserString is

```
"[\"5dc73d6e1c20540b24336681\",\"5dca64f4bf98ec2ada3b315e\"]"
```

This String is converted with Codable to the final body value with the other parameters.

```
- description : "location description"
  ▿ location : LocationCodable
    - latitude : "0.0"
    - longitude : "0.0"
    - description : "Test Ort"
- linked_users : "[\"5dc73d6e1c20540b24336681\",\"5dca64f4bf98ec2ada3b315e\"]"
```

If I call the API without the linked_users parameter it works fine.

Somebody knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `linked_users` is wrapped in outer braces? For example: `{ "linked_users": [ "5dc73d6e1c20540b24336681", "5dca64f4bf98ec2ada3b315e"] }`. JSON requires these outer braces to be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make correct model:

```
struct Model: Codable {

    var description: String!
    var location: LocationCodable!
    var linked_users: [String]!
}
```

and encode it, instead of encoding parameter `linked_users` itself.